# subtracting two lists while keeping duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, and I'd like to subtract one from the other.

I have seen people using sets, but my lists contain duplicates, so I believe this is not an option for me.

```
int_list = [(1,1), (-1, 210), (-1, 210)]
new_list = [(-1, 210)]

final_list = [item for item in int_list if item not in new_list]
```

I get `final_list = [(1,1)]`, but I would like to keep the second copy of `(-1,210)` in the final list. I understand why this is happening, but I do not know another way to subtract the lists. I guess I can return the final list as it is, then append any elements from int_list which appear more than once, and which also appear in the new_list, but I feel like there should be an easier way.
 any help appreciated

Comment: so if you wanted to remove both, would you set `new_list = [(-1, 210), (-1, 210)]`? Or are you only asking to remove ONE instance (the first instance?) of the values in `new_list`?

Comment: can the second list also contain duplicates?

Comment: if the second list was `new_list = [(-1,210), (-1,210)]`, then I would want neither of the copies to appear in the final list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for the first list and subtract that with a `Counter` of the second. Then you can recreate the list with the remaining counts:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

int_list = [(1,1), (-1, 210), (-1, 210)]
new_list = [(-1, 210)]

final_list_counts = Counter(int_list) - Counter(new_list)
final_list = list(chain(*[[t] * count for t, count in final_list_counts.items()]))
print(final_list)  # [(1, 1), (-1, 210)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a hack-ey way of doing this that also preserves ordering:

```
int_list = [(1,1), (-1, 210), (-1, 210)]
new_list = [(-1, 210)]

final_list = [item for item in int_list if item not in new_list or new_list.remove(item)]
# final_list == [(1, 1), (-1, 210)]
```

This makes sure we don't filter too many items from `int_list`. It should also work if `new_list` contains duplicates as well. Note that it mutates `new_list`, so make a copy beforehand if needed.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to rely on [side effects within a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects). You could easily do the same in a simple loop. On the other hand, I suppose one could argue that this is not purely for the side effect.

Comment: @pault I agree that a loop might be more clear, but I don't think the list comprehension is unwarranted. I am constructing a new list (it's not purely for side effects).

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
for x in new_list:
    if x in int_list: int_list.remove(x)
```

Note : `remove` removes the first matching value

Comment: Note that `Remove element from the list. Raises KeyError if element is not contained in the list.`

Comment: Thanks Chris. Updated answer.